# How to manage queue like system over multiple user and start/stop instance?

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework-2.3

(I'm sorry for the title, it was the best I could come up with)

I have a PlayFramework (2.3) app where my users can upload large csv files that will be processed.
Once the CSV is imported, I run a task that will pass over each new entry, and check a specific data with a request to an external API (for each entry).

Since this takes a long time, I do the checking asynchronously, but I'm facing a structural issue here :

1. User A upload a file with 100k lines
2. I add those 100k lines to my async code and start it
3. User B upload a file with 200k lines
4. I would add those new lines to the current async code
5. I stop the app (updating the code)
6. When restarting, it should start where it stopped.

I thought about a Queue system, but I would loose the interest when starting the app.

Any idea on how I can do this ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is structural, I am only going to focus on the high level implementation details :

> I stop the app (updating the code)

When you decide to stop the application, you need a way to gradually stop all running threads. For this, every thread that you start in your application should be registered with some sort of a thread manager. This way, when you decide to stop the application by clicking on a stop button/bringing down the app server, your thread manager knows what threads are running and will give these threads a chance to save their state or finish their work without allowing any new threads to be spawned before finally bringing down the main thread itself.

> When restarting, it should start where it stopped

To start from where you stopped, you need to save the state of the completed work somewhere. Assuming that you are using a Queue based system, you will have to serialize your queue before the app stops. This way, you won't lose the contents of the queue when you bring back the app.

Comment: This sounds reasonable to me. I second this high-level implementation description.